# Mesh with outlines

Tags: mesh

How do you create a mesh with outlines? When you draw a character on paper, you begin to draw outlines. The character is built of outlines before you draw colour. My mesh now doesn't have outlines and it need outlines to look as the reference in 3D. I watched 3D animation with outlines and got to create it with my character. I activated freestyle but see the mesh in rendered colours. Now i know how to render the mesh with freestyle in solid view. I need to know how to create outlines around parts with colour. One part is dark red and another is blue. How do i create outlines around the blue part? I have no idea how. I don't like stupid monkeys. Screw the monkey head. I need a solution that doesn't have stupid monkeys.

Comment: I would check some tutorials on Blender _Freestyle_ for that or _Grease Pencil_.

Answer (score 1):

#### Line Art (Grease Pencil)

You can easily add outlines for your scene with *Line Art*.

1. Add a *Scene Line Art* : <kbd>Maj</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> *> Grease Pencil > Scene Line Art*
2. Set to only silhouette, and tweak color and thickness as follows (*LineArt* selected) :

[image: Settings to apply to Line Art]

And that's it ! Any object you add will be used by the *Line Art* object.

3. From there you have a lot of settings to play with. For example, you can disable the *Line Art* for some objects :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To make Mesh outlines there are 2 methods :

**Method 1** (this works to export a model) :

First, duplicate your Mesh scale it, and flip it Normals

[image]

With enabling BackFace culling you can view the outlines in the viewport
[image]

Finally, Give it a Material
[image]

[image]

Don't forget to enable BackFace culling And disable shadow for the outline Material
[image]

[image]

**Note** :
This works in Blender if you are using a game engine you need to enable BackFace culling and disable shadow cast in the Material settings for this game engine for the material to make outlines work

**Method 2** (This works for animation rendering):

First, use Solidify Modifier and then follow these steps:
[image]

[image]

[image]

The material index works like this :

0=1, 1=2, 2=3..., etc

There are other methods using glsl language (like most of the AAA games) but it's a long way tho

I hope this helps :)

Sorry for my english